# Generics and multiple List<> searches

Tags: c#, list, generics

In my project, my data layer keeps a number of List collections to store the last returned data from SQl DB searches. I find myself repeating a lot of code. One in particular is used to see if a data object is already in the database, so that it can be updated instead of added. Here is an example:

```
public List<ClassA> ListClassA;
public List<ClassB> ListClassB;
    public override bool ContainsClassA(ClassA group)
    {
        if (null == group)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }
        return ListClassA.Where(x => x.ClassA_ID == group.ClassA_ID).ToList().Count > 0;
    }

    public override bool ContainsClassB(ClassB group)
    {
        if (null == group)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }
        return ListClassB.Where(x => x.ClassB_ID == group.ClassB_ID).ToList().Count > 0;
    }
```

Is there a way in which I can do this using the one function and Generics? 
Would I need to rename the index fields so that they match e.g. ClassA_ID and ClassB_ID to ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have both classes implement an interface with an ID property, and then use a generic with a constraint (`where T : [your interface name]`).

Also,

```
ListClassA.Where(x => x.ClassA_ID == group.ClassA_ID).ToList().Count > 0
```

is a bit redundant, you could just use

```
ListClassA.Any(x => x.ClassA_ID == group.ClassA_ID)
```

Comment: Hmm. Yes I was getting a feeling that I would need something like that. I hadn't though of the interface type - duh! Now I just need to add some mapping for properties and the Generics used to access the database!

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `Dictionary` instead of a `List` for caching:

```
 Dictionary<ClassA_ID, ClassA> classACache;
 ...
 classACache.ContainsKey(aitem.ClassA_ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement IEquatable<T> on your classes like this:

```
public class ClassA : IEquatable<ClassA>
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(ClassA other)
    {
        if (this.ID == other.ID)
            return true;

        return false;
    }
}
```

Then you can simply use the List<T>.Contains() method like this:

```
List<ClassA> ListOfClassA = new List<ClassA>();

ClassA ItemA = new ClassA() { ID = 1 };
ClassA ItemB = new ClassA() { ID = 2 };

ListOfClassA.Add(ItemA);

if (ListOfClassA.Contains(ItemA))
    Console.WriteLine("The list contains ItemA.");

if (ListOfClassA.Contains(ItemB))
    Console.WriteLine("The list contains ItemB.");
```

The output of the above code is:

```
The list contains ItemA.
```